# How to get the current value from a select_tag to another in view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I have 2 select tags, the first is Teams and the second is for member ! I want the second select tag to be filled depending on the selection of the Team.

Example :

```
Team1 has user1 and user2
Team2 has user3 and user4
```

I want if if I select the `team1` the second select tag would have only the values of its members which will be `user1` and `user2`.

**PS: I know how to invoke ajax and pass them to controller and deal with params, I just want to know if there is any way I can get the current value in view and pass to the next select tag**

Comment: If you are using jquery, you can get the value selected from select tag as  `$("#id_of_select_1).val()`. And depending on this value you can add options tag to select tag using append method of jquery.

Comment: Another option is to create an api end-point which you can hit with a JS function which will respond with all users of the team selected as json. 
Put an onChange="yourJsFunction(this.value(represents the team selected)) in the <select>.  Inside of the js function you write, grab the id of your users select box and populate it with the json response of users.

Comment: Also I do not think you can do what you are asking solely with rails.  I mean you can but not without a refresh, which is ugly.

Comment: thank you kparekh01, you actually understood what I mean

Answer (score 0):

You can do by ajax calls and [select2](https://select2.org/) option population, firstly write a change event like(expecting that you already included select2 in js source)

```
$('#first-select').change(function(event) {
  var first_element;
  first_element = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('#second-select').empty();
    },
    url: 'your ajax url',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
      role_id: first_element.val()
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('#second-select').select2({
        data: data,
        placeholder: 'Select User',
        allowClear: true
      });
    }
  });
});
```

create a action to deliver the users list for a given team id in format json.

And it's done.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I did mention that I know all these solutions, I just wanted a ruby snippet